# Как убрать кеширование верстки в VUE

Tags: vue.js, кэширование

Использую VUE через CDN. Есть проблема. При изменении какого либо элемента в верстке, VUE эти изменения не отображает. Обычная очистка кэша не помогает. Помогает "жесткая очистка кэша и перезагрузка". Но клиентам не будешь ведь инструкцию писать что да как надо делать, что бы какой-то элемент новый появился в верстке. Я использую `computed` и `return` -ом возвращаю просто массив данных и вставляю в скрытый блок на сайте. Это иногда помогает(заставляет vue перерендерить страницу). Но есть ли какой-нибудь нормальный выход из этой ситуации? Чтобы при изменении кода, не приходилось очищать кэш и верстка на странице обновлялась.

Comment: обычно в js файлы добавляют хэш файла например `main.123abc.js`,  чтобы кэширование было на конкретную версию, а не по имени файла

Comment: Мда как вариант. Напиши как ответ. Зачту. Применю этот способ.

Comment: @Komdosh Пока проверить не успел. Но реализовал). И скорее всего не main.123abc.js а наверно вот так main..js?123abc

Comment: ну можно конечно и так, но обычно собирают index.6c6920e8d45f0070.js. https://survivejs.com/webpack/optimizing/adding-hashes-to-filenames/

Comment: @Komdosh Спасибо за ссылку. На всякий сделаю сразу два способа :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавляйте хэш файла в название, чтобы кэш CDN ориентировался на версию файла, а не на его имя.

Например в webpack можно настроить сборку c хэшем в имени

```
const config = {
  output: {
    path: PATHS.build,
    filename: "[name].[contenthash].js",
  },
};
```

Пример файлов:

```
main.d587bbd6e38337f5accd.js
vendor.dc746a5db4ed650296e1.js
```